# what does this sentence mean in Pine-Script V3?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

the sentence is:

```
catr(_m) => (cum(tr)/(n+1))*_m
```

I am seeking to transfer this sentence to Pine-Script V5.
No idea of what `_m` and `n` means here, and how to transfer them into V5 syntax?
They both appear only in this sentence.

Comment: Showing the full script might make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is renamed as `bar_index` in v4 and above. So, it's the index of the current bar.

`_m` is just a parameter name.